# Converting qmake to cmake, how do I set Debug vs Release, and similar configuration options?

Tags: c++, cmake, qmake

I'll start by saying that I'm a total noob to cmake, but it's what most people use and I need to finally make the switch from qmake. I'm trying to convert the following project file:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------
# This file is generated by the Qt Visual Studio Tools.
# ------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://www.toptal.com/qt/vital-guide-qmake
# NOTE: Debug build should use /MDd runtime library, and release should use /MD (may be default for Qt)
# TODO: Convert to cmake: https://www.executionunit.com/blog/2014/01/22/moving-from-qmake-to-cmake/

message("Beginning qmake build of project_name.pro")

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = project_name
QT += core \
      opengl \ 
      gui \
      widgets \
      concurrent \ # Mutexes/multithreading
      openglextensions \
      multimedia \
      gamepad \ # Controller support
      network # TCP/IP

# Set compiler flags /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MP # Multiprocess compile, much faster

# MSVC versions after 15.3 are fickle with the flags required to use more modern c++ variants
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= /std:c++17 # Add if not there, this may be the ticket
# QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17 # For GCC/Clang
# QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1z

# Set general configuration options /////////////////////////////////////////////////
CONFIG += c++latest # Add support for c++17.
# CONFIG += c++1z # another attempt at C++17 support
CONFIG += qt # console # The target is a Qt application or library and requires the Qt library and header files
CONFIG += thread # Thread support is enabled. This is enabled when CONFIG includes qt, which is the default.
CONFIG += debug_and_release # Creates additional debug and release folders, but need it for debug

CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = ../app/debug
    DEFINES += DEBUG_MODE
} 
else {
    DESTDIR = ../app/release
}

# Replace O2 flag with O3 flag
#CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
#    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
#   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
#   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3
#}

# Do not display debug output in release mode
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) : CONFIG += debug_info
CONFIG(release, debug|release) : DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT

CONFIG += no_lflags_merge # Ensures that the list of libraries stored in the LIBS variable is not reduced to a list of unique values before it is used.
# CONFIG += CONSOLE # makes this a console application
CONFIG -= flat # flattens file hierarchy, subtract if this is not desired

# Defines //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
DEFINES += _UNICODE _ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE WIN64 QT_DLL QT_OPENGL_LIB QT_OPENGLEXTENSIONS_LIB QT_WIDGETS_LIB
DEFINES += DEVELOP_MODE
DEFINES += LINALG_USE_EIGEN
INCLUDEPATH += ./qt_generated \
    . \
    ./qt_generated/$(ConfigurationName) 
    
LIBS += -lopengl32 \
    -lglu32 
DEPENDPATH += .


# Add Libraries ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# Don't forget to add to unit tests project as well, or else Intellisense errors will carry over
# Include PythonQt and required libraries
# Maybe not needed here, since python.prf is included when PythonQt is built?
# Note that both windows and linux style library links work in windows
# LIBS += -L$$(PYTHON_LIB)/ -lpython$$(PYTHON_VERSION) # L"PATH" adds PATH to library search directory list, and -lName loads library Name during linking

# Enable import <PythonQt.h>
# INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/src/third_party/pythonqt

#include ( ../third_party/PythonQt/build/python.prf )   #Was pulled from  PythonQt build
include ( ../third_party/PythonQt/build/common.prf )  
include ( ../third_party/PythonQt/build/PythonQt.prf )  
#include ( ../third_party/PythonQt/build/PythonQt_QtAll.prf )  


# Compile against release version of python
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) : DEFINES += PYTHONQT_USE_RELEASE_PYTHON_FALLBACK

# Eigen
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/src/third_party/eigen \
               $$PWD/src/third_party/eigen/Eigen

# ASSIMP
# To be able to write <module.h>
INCLUDEPATH += ../third_party/assimp/assimp-5.0.0/include
INCLUDEPATH += ../third_party/assimp/assimp-5.0.0/build/include
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) : LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/assimp -lassimp_d
CONFIG(release, debug|release) : LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/assimp -lassimp

# PhysX
DEFINES += PX_PHYSX_STATIC_LIB
INCLUDEPATH += ../../PhysX/physx/include \
               ../../PhysX/pxshared/include
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) { 
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysX_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXCharacterKinematic_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXCommon_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXCooking_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXExtensions_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXFoundation_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXPvdSDK_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/debug -lPhysXVehicle_static_32
}
CONFIG(release, debug|release) { 
    # Always needed
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXCommon_static_32
    
    # Always needed
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysX_static_32
    
    # Always needed
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXFoundation_static_32
    
    # To cook geometry data on the fly
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXCooking_static_32
    
    # Other
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXCharacterKinematic_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXExtensions_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXPvdSDK_static_32
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/physx/release -lPhysXVehicle_static_32
}

# FreeType
INCLUDEPATH +=  ../third_party/freetype-2.10.1/include
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) : LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/freetype/debug -lfreetype
CONFIG(release, debug|release) : LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/freetype/release -lfreetype

# SoLoud
INCLUDEPATH += ../third_party/soloud/include
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) { 
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/soloud/debug -lsoloud_x86_d
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/soloud/debug -lsoloud_static_x86_d
}
CONFIG(release, debug|release) { 
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/soloud/release -lsoloud_x86
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/soloud/release -lsoloud_static_x86
}


# Include Visual Leak Detector //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
INCLUDEPATH += "../third_party/Visual Leak Detector/include/"
LIBS        += -L"../third_party/Visual Leak Detector/lib/Win32"    
    
               
# Set directories //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MOC_DIR += ./qt_generated/moc
OBJECTS_DIR += ./qt_generated/obj
UI_DIR += ./qt_generated/ui
RCC_DIR += ./qt_generated

message("Loaded .pro files, now loading .pri")

# Load in library files for project
include(project_name.pri)

message("Loaded .pri files")
```

Now, this file is big and scary, so I've been slowly working through it to find analogous functionality between cmake and qmake. However, I'm stuck. I can't seem to wrap my head around how I would convert the following bit over:

```
CONFIG += c++latest # Add support for c++17.
CONFIG += qt # console # The target is a Qt application or library and requires the Qt library and header files
CONFIG += thread # Thread support is enabled. This is enabled when CONFIG includes qt, which is the default.
CONFIG += debug_and_release # Creates additional debug and release folders, but need it for debug

CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = ../app/debug
    DEFINES += DEBUG_MODE
} 
else {
    DESTDIR = ../app/release
}

# Do not display debug output in release mode
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) : CONFIG += debug_info
CONFIG(release, debug|release) : DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT

CONFIG += no_lflags_merge # Ensures that the list of libraries stored in the LIBS variable is not reduced to a list of unique values before it is used.
# CONFIG += CONSOLE # makes this a console application
CONFIG -= flat # flattens file hierarchy, subtract if this is not desired
```

For starters, it's not super clear to me which of the CONFIG options are even still necessary. Can I do away with adding `qt`, `thread`, `debug_and_release`, etc.? If not, then what would the equivalent functionality in cmake be?

Even trickier is the `CONFIG(debug, debug|release) :` logic. Is there a way to have Debug vs. Release settings in cmake like I currently do? My end goal is to have cmake putting out an MSVC studio project exactly like my qmake setup is doing, so I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: `Is there a way` Yes. `how do I set Debug vs Release, and similar configuration options?` Should be explained in some decent cmake manual. What research did you do?

Comment: There are generator expressions.  I don't think translating is the way to go. You will probably want to start with simpler examples.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've been googling and scouring the web for information on how to configure for different built modes in cmake, but it's challenging without knowing what exactly I'm looking for. If you could maybe provide some actual info instead of criticizing my google-fu, that'd be wonderful.

Comment: You don't configure for modules in the same way at all.

Comment: You probably want to start here: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html)

Comment: @drescherjm Can you elaborate at all? That means very little to me. I was thinking of checking the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE for "Debug" or "Release", and defining the conditional logic that way, but that doesn't seem correct because it sounds pretty static. https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GScZBF7fhjkJ:https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-d

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I have seen that page. It doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I set Debug vs Release, and similar configuration options?

There are two common options. A plain `if`:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
   target_compile_definitions(the_target PUBLIC DEBUG_MODE)
elif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
   target_compile_definitions(the_target PUBLIC QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
endif()
```

But note that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and `STREQUAL` is  *case sensitive*, so if someone does `cmake .... -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release` it will just fail. Some programmers work around that by first uppercasing the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and then working with uppercased value (or lowercasing). Anyway, another method is to use generator expressions and it looks better and ignores case:

```
target_compile_definitions(the_target PUBLIC
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:DEBUG_MODE>
    $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT>
)
```

There are also many `CMAKE_BLA_BLA_<configuration>` options, like [`CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_DEBUG.html), `CMAME_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` etc.

> c++latest # Add support for c++17.

Use `set_target_properties(the_target PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17 CXx_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)` or use `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` variables.

> and I do away with adding qt, thread

Use `find_library` to find a library. There are many `find_package` to find various common libraries.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very helpful! I'll do some reading on generator expressions to better understand the syntax, but I get the gist of what you're saying. I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: So, looking at this more, if I wanted to add multiple defines for each configuration, would I just do something like this?:

`target_compile_definitions(the_target PUBLIC $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:DEBUG_MODE OTHER_OPTION> $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT ANOTHER_OPTION>
)`

Comment: Or, I like to keep one option per line, and do separate `$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE:QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT> $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:ANOTHER_OPTION>`. It's easier to work with lines. (I think I had problems with spaces in generator expressions, but I am not sure, I try to avoid spaces)

Comment: Got it, I can do that to be safe. Thanks again!